# Overload [] operator in C++ to support custom set function

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a C++ class which simulates an array and for manipulating its members I implemented two functions: `set(size_t index, size_t value)` and `get(size_t index)`. I would like to overload the [] operator to have the following functionality:

```
MyCustomArray[index] = value //->set(size_t index, size_t value)
```

And

```
value = MyCustomArray[index] //->get(size_t index)
```

`get` can be easily implemented with overload, but I don't know how to implement `set` because I need the parameter `value` beforehand.

My class is an implementation of a fixed-word array (elements in the array have at most P bits, where P is a parameter and it can be less than the regular machine word). To support this functionality, `set` and `get` manipulate a range of bits of a value in a regular C/C++ array.

Is it possible to overload in this scenario?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take inspiration from `std::vector<bool>` and return a temporary proxy object that itself overloads `operator =`.

Comment: @Quentin Someone should have been generous enough to grant it its own name, instead of making it a wart on `std::vector` breaking generic code, but it's a good example for the needed functionality.

Comment: @PeteBecker the bit-twiddling in the last paragraph seems to prevent this simple solution.

Comment: @Deduplicator alas! But yeah, demonstration purposes only.

Comment: @Quentin -- good point. I didn't read all the way to the end. :-( Removed.

Comment: One workaround vector being too helpful with the bool specialization, `enum class Bool : bool { False = false, True = true };` then `std::vector<Bool>`.  Still a bit of marshaling bother data to/from the vector, since enum class's are snobbish.

Comment: Do you actually need to call `get/set` from `operator[]`? It is simple if you just want to access the data in way that allows modification. Simply return a reference to the object and your required operation will work.

Answer (score 5):

This is just like what std::vector::operator[] is doing - using a proxy object.

```
class MyCustomArray
{
public:
    using value_type = unsigned;
    class Proxy
    {
    public:
        friend class MyCustomArray;
        operator value_type() const 
        {
            return m_customArray.get(m_index);
        }
        Proxy & operator=(value_type value)
        {
            m_customArray.set(m_index, value);
            return *this;
        }
    private:
        Proxy(MyCustomArray & customArray, size_t index) 
            : m_customArray(customArray), m_index(index) {}
        MyCustomArray & m_customArray;
        size_t m_index;
    };
    value_type operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return get(index);
    }
    Proxy operator[](size_t index) 
    {
        return Proxy(*this, index);
    }
    value_type get(size_t index) const;
    void set(size_t index, value_type value);
private:
    /// The data goes here
};
```

Then

```
void work(MyCustomArray & arr)
{
    // Return a Proxy object, and call operator= over it.
    arr[3] = 5;

    // arr_2 is of type MyCustomArray::Proxy
    auto arr_2 = arr[2];
    arr_2 = 1; // modifies arr[2]
    unsigned x = arr_2; // gets 1 from arr[2] 

    // This works, due to auto conversion to value_type:
    std::cout << arr_2 << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this approach, and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, this can be accomplished by having `operator[]` return a proxy object, which is how `std::vector<bool>` performs its magic.

In your case, it would look something along these lines:

```
struct MyCustomArray;

struct ArrayMemberRef {
  MyCustomArray* target_;
  std::size_t index_;

  ArrayMemberRef& operator=(std::size_t value);
  operator std::size_t();
};

struct MyCustomArray {
  ArrayMemberRef operator[](std::size_t index) {
    return ArrayMemberRef{this, index}; 
  }

  void set(std::size_t index, std::size_t value);
  int get(std::size_t index);
};

ArrayMemberRef& ArrayMemberRef::operator=(std::size_t value) {
  target_->set(index_, value);
  return *this;
}

ArrayMemberRef::operator std::size_t() {
  return target_->get(index_);
}
```